# iterator use about card

Tags: c++, iterator

There is something wrong with my program.

The error is "function call missing argument list".

I am making a card program to show cards. I don't know how to use iterators correctly.

```
void Deck::ShowDeck()
    {
        vector<Card>::iterator dealt;

        for (dealt = cards.begin(); dealt != cards.end(); dealt++)
        {
            cout<<*dealt<<" ";
        }
    }
```

here is my deck.h
so  could you please give me more specific answer? I changed '*dealt' to 'dealt->str'  but it is still wrong
    #ifndef _DECK_H_
    #define _DECK_H_

```
#include "card.h"
#include <vector>

/**
 * This class represents a standard 52-card poker deck
 */
class Deck
{
public:
   /**
    * Default constructor. This will initialize and shuffle the deck
    */
   Deck();

   /**
    * Reinitilaize the deck and shuffle it.
    */
   void Shuffle();

   /**
    * Dump out the contents of the current deck, minus already dealt cards
    */
   void ShowDeck();

   /**
    * Return a vector of cards that are dealt. 
    * @param count number of cards to deal
    * @return a set of cards from the front of the deck
    */
   std::vector<Card> Deal( int count );


private:
   std::vector<Card> cards;
   std::vector<Card>::iterator dealt;
   std::vector<Card> deal;


/* Your code here */

};

#endif //_DECK_H_
```

this is card.cpp

```
#include "card.h"
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

Card::Card()
{
}



std::string Card::str()
{
   ostringstream os;
   os << valToStr() << suitToStr();
   return os.str();
}



std::string Card::suitToStr()
{
  switch(suit)
  {
  case 1:
      return"C";
      break;
  case 2:
      return"D";
      break;
  case 3:
      return"H";
      break; 
  case 4:
      return"S";
      break;
    default:
        break;
  }
}

std::string Card::valToStr()
{
   switch (value)
   {
       case 2:
           return "TWO"; break;
       case 3:
           return "THREE"; break;
       case 4:
           return "FOUR"; break;
       case 5:
           return "FIVE"; break;
       case 6:
           return "SIX"; break;
       case 7:
           return "SEVEN"; break;
       case 8:
           return "EIGHT";  break;
       case 9:
           return "NINE"; break;
       case 10:
           return "TEN"; break;
       case 11:
           return "JACK"; break;
       case 12:
           return "QUEEN"; break;
       case 13:
           return "KING"; break;
       case 14:
           return "ACE"; break;
       default: break;
   }
}

/* Your code here */
```

And this is card.h

```
#ifndef _CARD_H_
#define _CARD_H_

#include <string>
/**
 * Card class. This class represents a single playing card 
 */

class Card
{
public:
   /**
    * Suits of playing cards
    */
   typedef enum SUITS { CLUBS = 1 , DIAMONDS, HEARTS, SPADES } SUITES;

   /**
    * The value of the card: 2 through Ace
    */
   typedef enum COUNT { TWO = 2, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX, SEVEN, EIGHT, NINE, TEN, JACK, QUEEN, KING, ACE } COUNT;

   /** 
    * Default constructor
    */
   Card();



   /**
    * Constructor to initialize our suit and value
    *
    * @param _suit enum of SUITS
    * @param _val  value of the card (COUNT enum)
    */
   Card( Card::SUITS _suit, Card::COUNT _val )
   {

   this->suit=_suit;
   this->value=_val;

   }


   /**
    * Get a string representation of the card.
    * @return string in the format similar to this: "10D", which would be 10
    * of diamonds
    */
   std::string str();

   /**
    * Accessor to get this card's suit
    * @return value of this card's suit
    */
   SUITS getSuit()
   {
       return suit;
   }


   /**
    * Accessor to get this card's value
    * @return value of this card
    */
   COUNT getValue()
   {
       return value;
   }


private:
   Card::SUITS suit;
   Card::COUNT value;
   std::string suitToStr();
   std::string valToStr();


/* Your code here */


};

#endif // _CARD_H_
```

Comment: What is the problem with this code? It is not clear what does it do and what it is supposed to do.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code snippet you've shown us. Where exactly is the error occurring?

Comment: The error may be due to your code not having an `operator<<` defined for the class `Card`.

Comment: You should realize that dereferencing an iterator produces an object of type `Card` (the type of `*dealt` is `Card`), so you are basically trying do use `cout` with a `Card` object. Do you have an `ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Card& card)` defined?

Comment: I don't have ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Card& card) defined , but I have ostringstream  , then how can I do ?

Answer (score 1):

The iterator is just an object used to traverse elements of Card (whatever that is, you don't exactly specify). You can access a member of the object you are traversing with the iterator like so:

```
void Deck::ShowDeck()
{
    vector<Card>::iterator dealt;

    for (dealt = cards.begin(); dealt != cards.end(); dealt++)
    {
        cout<<dealt->suitToStr<<" "; // equivalent to (*dealt).cardType
    }
}
```

Please be more specific and I can edit this answer to better help you.

Comment: Thank you , but could you please be more specific ? I changed to dealt->cardType but it still wrong   I have added some code now

Comment: What exactly is "Card"? I cannot help you until I know what members Card has.

Comment: I have added card.cpp and card.h . Thank you for help.

Comment: Try it now. That code should print the suit it is. This will give you a better idea of how iterators are used. Also, check this out, I still have a feeling you don't quite know how this is working http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/